# Incoming web hook doesn't honor resource filters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We have configured an incoming web hook and pipelines in one of the organization. The web hook is called from second organization pipeline for its deployment. The same web hook is used to call multiple pipelines with different filters as below.

```
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: testhook
      connection: testhookconnection
      filters:
        - path: name      
          value: "pipeline1"

resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: testhook
      connection: testhookconnection
      filters:
        - path: name      
          value: "pipeline2"
```

Request URL: https://dev.azure.com/abc/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/testhook?api-version=6.0-preview

Sample Body: `{"name":"pipeline1"}`

I was able to trigger individual pipelines by changing filter values till yesterday. Now I see a strange behavior when I called it from other pipelines/rest API. The web hook honors only one pipeline based on the order when it was created.

1. If I call a pipeline with filter pipeline1, this will trigger
   pipeline1. If I call a pipeline with filter pipeline2, this will
   return 200 status but it won't trigger the corresponding pipeline.
2. If I delete the pipeline1 and try to trigger pipeline2, this will
   trigger pipeline2.

Please suggest a solution. Any help would be appreciated.